# MySQL (v 5.5) greater than or equals to operator is adding unknown amounts

Tags: mysql, operators

I’m using the query below to sum together all repeat transactions that customers make for a given company id. Customer information is stored on the contact table and the transaction details are on the customer transactions table, the tables are linked through the contact_id. I’m getting some strange behavior in the WHERE clause. The t.amount column is a DECIMAL(15,2).

Using `WHERE t.amount > 0.0` gives a result around 170,000. However using `WHERE t.amount >= 0.0` increases the result to 200,000. Even stranger still, when I try `WHERE t.amount = 0.0`, the query returns 0.0. Data from other companies exhibits this same amount difference between `>` and `>=`.

`SELECT SUM(amount) AS amount 
FROM (
SELECT *,
           @counter := IF(@customer_id = b.contact_id, @counter + 1, 1) AS txn_number, 
           @customer_id := b.contact_id 
    FROM (
        SELECT t.contact_id, SUM(t.amount) AS amount, t.transacted_at AS transacted_at
        FROM customer_transactions t
        INNER JOIN contact con ON con.contact_id = t.contact_id
        WHERE con.company_id = #CompanyId
        AND t.amount >= 0.0
        AND t.is_paid = true
        AND t.transacted_at IS NOT NULL 
        GROUP BY t.contact_id, DATE(t.transacted_at)
        ORDER BY t.contact_id, t.transacted_at ASC
    ) AS b
) AS ct
WHERE ct.txn_number > 1`

In short, using only `>` gives returns one result, using `>=` returns a larger result even though it's being set as `>= 0.0` Is there any reason why this would happen?

Comment: Datatype of `amount`?

Comment: Why not have a look at which rows are in the first set that aren't in the second and see what values you're dealing with.

Comment: I agree with @tadman. I don't think you are debugging this very well

Comment: you've got the contact_id

Comment: @Hackerman the amount is a DECIMAL set to (15, 2)

Comment: @Drew I've looked at the diff between the two data sets and the only difference is that the larger data set has several additional rows containing transaction amounts of 0.0

Comment: I am sure I could find it :p